# ScientificForm problem

Tags: output-formatting

Consider this code:

```
ScientificForm[1., 8, NumberFormat -> (Row[If[#3 == "", {#1, "E", 0}, {#1, "E", #3}]] &)]
(* 1.E0 *)

ToString@ScientificForm[1., 8, NumberFormat -> (Row[If[#3 == "", {#1, "E", 0}, {#1, "E", #3}]] &)]
(* 1.E0E0 *)
```

Why is there an extra "E0" in the second output?

Comment: Use `{#1, "E", "0"}` instead of `{#1, "E", 0}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use `{#1, "E", "0"}` instead of `{#1, "E", 0}`, or you can use `ToString[#, StandardForm] &`. But the former one is safer I think, cause I noticed a parameter other than integer will **crash the kernel** on my 9.0.1:

```
ScientificForm[1., 8, 
  NumberFormat -> (Row[
      If[#3 == "", {#1, "E", 1.2}, {#1, "E", #3}]] &)] // ToString
```

Comment: Thanks:) Do you know why `ToString` adds the extra "E0"?

Comment: @xslittlegrass I'm not sure. But `ToString` uses `OutputForm` by default, so this really is not about `ToString`, but about formatting. Maybe checking the underlying boxes will reveal some detail.